# recurrence relation of a language

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, regular-language

I am looking at the following:

[image: automaton]

Consider a language $X$ which consists of all bitstrings with no more than 2 consecutive zeros (represented by the above automaton). Next consider a sequence $s_n$ which is the number of words in $X$ with length $n$. How do I come up with a recurrence relation which defines the sequence $s_n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A word in $X$ of length $n\ge3$ ends in a one followed by $0\le k\le2$ zeros, and what comes before the one is a word in $X$ of length $n-k-1$; so $s_n=s_{n-1}+s_{n-2}+s_{n-3}$.

Comment: Can't the word end with something other than just zeros? For example 1001 could be a valid word in X

Comment: @user141834: That ends in a one followed by $k=0$ zeros.

Comment: Would the same principle apply if it were more than 3 consecutive zeros? @joriki

Comment: @user141834: Does the argument make any specific use of the number $3$? Which part of the argument might fail for other numbers of zeros?

Comment: I meant if we were to consider the language with no more than 3 consecutive zeros, would the definition of the sequence follow the same pattern?

Comment: With that being said, $0 \le k \le 2$ would be the part of the argument that would fail for 3 consecutive zeros

Comment: so if we were to do the same thing, but not allowing more than 3 consecutive zeros, the sequence would be something like $s_n=s_{n-1}+s_{n-2}+s_{n-3} + s_{n-4}$ ?

Comment: @user141834: Yes, not just something like that, exactly that (but that's the recurrence relation, not the sequence).

Comment: could you please explain how you deduced the recurrence relation in your original answer? I don't quite follow. I get up to the part where what comes before the one is a word in X of length $n-k-1$, but the deduction of the sequence recurrence is not immediately apparent to me. Thank you

Comment: @user141834: The three cases $k=0,1,2$ are mutually exclusive: After the last one in the word, there are either $0$, $1$ or $2$ zeros. As you say, before the one is a word in X of length $n-k-1$, and in fact, *all* such words can occur there. Thus there is exactly one word of length $n$ for each word of lengh $n-1$, $n-2$ or $n-3$, which is obtained by adding a one and $0$, $1$ or $2$ zeros, respectively. I hope that's clearer?

Comment: @user141834: In other words, there is a bijection between the set of words of length $n$ and the union of the sets of words of length $n-1$, $n-2$, $n-3$ -- given a word of length $n$, you strip the last one and any zeros after it; given a word of length $n-1$, $n-2$ or $n-3$ you add a $1$ and pad it with zeros until it has length $n$.

Comment: I see, that makes it a bit more clearer. Could you please give me an example of a sequence that would satisfy the recurrence relation that you have identified? I understand the concepts that you have outlined in your aforementioned comments, but struggling to see how it all fits together to form the recurrence relation. I will accept your answer :)

Comment: @user141834: You can pick any initial values $s_0$, $s_1$, $s_2$ and successively apply the recurrence relation to them to obtain a sequence that satisfies the recurrence relation. In particular, using the numbers of bitstrings with no more than $2$ consecutive zeros as initial values ($s_0=1$, $s_1=2$, $s_2=4$), you get the desired sequence: $s_3=1+2+4=7$, $s_4=2+4+7=13$, etc. If you want a closed form, you can solve the characteristic equation $\lambda^3=\lambda^2+\lambda+1$, but [the result is not nice](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x^3%3Dx^2%2Bx%2B1&dataset=).